# The "touch" command is either mispelled or could not be found on git command on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, git-bash

I am trying to run the below command:
"touch hello.html"
The error I am getting is: "touch command is either mispelled or could not be found"

I tried- "npm install touch-cli -g"

Please can you help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) to execute this such commands. In git bash commands such "touch", "vim", "nano" etc. should work without having to install them separate.

Otherwise, try to restart your system and check if the npm global directory is in your path environment variable.

Comment: So I have been using the GiytBash on Windows as you suggested. And now I am getting some other error which is, "'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I tried npm install touc cmd touch-cli -g cmd too, but doesn't work

Comment: Ah I see, you are executing the commands via cmd. After installing GitBash you can use the git bash to execute this commands instead of cmd.